# Magento 2 Data Migration Tool Config

Tags: magento2.3, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration-tool

Following that guide

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-configure.html

I choose to configure migration in a separate module as recommended.

But when run

```
bin/magento migrate:settings -r app/code/Bileamara/Migration/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.4.0/config.xml
```

I got the following error:

> Invalid map filename:
>   /mnt/vdb/vhosts/example.com/subdomains/dev/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/settings.xml

but what is expected is that the script looking for files first in the custom module than in the vendor folder.

Any help?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @BlueC check the answere

Comment: Thanks I was hoping they built the migration tool in such a way that configuring it in a custom module would automatically use the correct paths with fallback to the shipped .dist files. Seems not. Apparently another way is to hard-code the _absolute_ (!!) path into the  <settings_map_file> in config.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to make it works in the following way:

app/code/Vendor/Migration/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Migration\Reader\Map" type="Vendor\Migration\Reader\Map" />
  <preference for="Migration\Reader\Groups" type="Vendor\Migration\Reader\Groups" />
  <preference for="Migration\Reader\ClassMap" type="Vendor\Migration\Reader\ClassMap" />
  <preference for="Migration\Reader\Settings" type="Vendor\Migration\Reader\Settings" />
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Migration/Reader/ClassMap.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Migration\Reader;

/**
 * Class ClassMap
 */
class ClassMap extends \Migration\Reader\ClassMap
{

    /**
     * Validating xml file
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected function validate()
    {
        $mapFile = $this->config->getOption(self::MAP_FILE_OPTION);
        $rootDir = dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $configFile = $rootDir . $mapFile;
        if (!is_file($configFile)) {
            return parent::validate();
        }
        $xml = file_get_contents($configFile);
        $document = new \Magento\Framework\Config\Dom($xml, $this->validationState);

        if (!$document->validate($rootDir .'etc/' . self::CONFIGURATION_SCHEMA)) {
            throw new Exception('XML file is invalid.');
        }

        $this->xml = new \DOMXPath($document->getDom());
        return $this;
    }
}
```

app/code/Vendor/Migration/Reader/Groups.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Migration\Reader;

/**
 * Class Groups
 */
class Groups extends \Migration\Reader\Groups
{
    /**
     * Init configuration
     *
     * @param string $groupsFile
     * @return $this
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function init($groupsFile)
    {
        $xmlFile = $this->getThisRootDir() . $groupsFile;
        if (!is_file($xmlFile)) {
            return parent::init($groupsFile);
        }

        $xml = file_get_contents($xmlFile);
        $document = new \Magento\Framework\Config\Dom($xml, $this->validationState);

        if (!$document->validate($this->getRootDir() .'etc/' . self::CONFIGURATION_SCHEMA)) {
            throw new Exception('XML file is invalid.');
        }

        $this->xml = new \DOMXPath($document->getDom());
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Migration Tool Configuration Dir
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getThisRootDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
}
```

app/code/Vendor/Migration/Reader/Map.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Migration\Reader;

/**
 * Class Map
 */
class Map extends \Migration\Reader\Map
{

    /**
     * Init configuration
     *
     * @param string $mapFile
     * @return $this
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected function init($mapFile)
    {
        $this->ignoredDocuments = [];
        $this->wildcards = null;

        $configFile = $this->getThisRootDir() . $mapFile;
        if (!is_file($configFile)) {
            return parent::init($mapFile);
        }

        $xml = file_get_contents($configFile);
        $document = new \Magento\Framework\Config\Dom($xml, $this->validationState);

        if (!$document->validate($this->getRootDir() .'etc/' . self::CONFIGURATION_SCHEMA)) {
            throw new Exception('XML file is invalid.');
        }

        $this->xml = new \DOMXPath($document->getDom());
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Migration Tool Configuration Dir
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getThisRootDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }

}
```

app/code/Vendor/Migration/Reader/Settings.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Migration\Reader;

use Migration\Exception;

/**
 * Class Settings
 */
class Settings extends \Migration\Reader\Settings
{

    /**
     * Validating xml file
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected function validate()
    {
        $mapFile = $this->config->getOption(self::MAP_FILE_OPTION);
        $rootDir = dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $configFile = $rootDir . $mapFile;
        if (!is_file($configFile)) {
            return parent::validate();
        }

        $xml = file_get_contents($configFile);
        $document = new \Magento\Framework\Config\Dom($xml, $this->validationState);

        if (!$document->validate($rootDir .'etc/' . self::CONFIGURATION_SCHEMA)) {
            throw new Exception('XML file is invalid.');
        }

        $this->xml = new \DOMXPath($document->getDom());
        return $this;
    }
}
```

I hope will help someone.